# Running .exe files from a web application

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I am attempting to program a web-based application that will allow a user to input information (specifically, integers) into form fields, add the information entered as an entry in a .def file, run '.exe' files (written in C++) on the file, and then display output on the screen after clicking on a "submit" button. I have written functions to run the .exe files in JavaScript, but they don't work. Here is what I have so far:

The input screen has this code (HTML file):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html><head></head>><body><h1><i>The University of Vermont<br>Department of Medical     Biostatistics<br>Study Randomization Page</i></h1>
<?php
    $study = "study";
    $site = "site";
    $gender = "gender";
    $age = "age";
    $result = "result";
?>

Please Input Your Study Information Below:<br><br>
<form id="form1" action="file:///C:/Documents and Settings/cody/Desktop/DMB_RD_2.php"     method="post">
Study Number:<br>   <input name="study" type="int"><br>
Site Number:<br>    <input name="site" type="int"><br>
Subject Gender:<br> <input name="gender" type="int"><br>
Subject Age:<br>    <input name="age" type="int"><br>
Lab Result:<br>     <input name="result" type="int"><br>
<input value="Submit" class="button" type="submit">
</form>
</body></html>
Here is the page it is connected to (PHP file);
<script type="text/javascript" src="DMB++2JS.js"></script>
<script type="text" src="DMB Round 2.html"></script>
</head>
Here is the information that you input:<br /><br />
Study Number: <?php echo $_POST["study"]; ?><br />
Site Number: <?php echo $_POST["site"]; ?><br />
Subject Gender: <?php echo $_POST["gender"]; ?><br />
Subject Age: <?php echo $_POST["age"]; ?><br />
Lab Result: <?php echo $_POST["result"]; ?><br />
<br />
The following functions will randomize your data. Please indicated which method you would like to use by clicking on the button of the randomization method that you would like to use:<br /><br />
<input type="button" href="blockfn()" onclick="javascript:blockfn(); return     true;">Block Function</button><br />
<input type="button" href="d2rfn()" onclick="javascript:d2rfn(); return true;">Random Distance Function</button><br />
<input type="button" href="d2dfn()" onclick="javascript:d2dfn(); return true;">Determinate Distance Function</button><br />
<input type="button" href="minimizefn()" onclick="javascript:minimizefn(); return true;">Minimization Function</button><br />
<input type="button" href="pocockfn()" onclick="javascript:pocockfn(); return true;">Pocock Function</button><br />
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the JavaScript file with the functions written in it:

```
function d2rfn(){
    var oShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
    var commandtoRun = "C:\Documents and Settings\cody\Desktop\C++ Programs\D2R001.def"; 
    oShell.ShellExecute(commandtoRun,"","","open","1");
}
function d2dfn(){
    var oShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
    var commandtoRun = "C:\Documents and Settings\cody\Desktop\C++ Programs\D2D001.def"; 
    oShell.ShellExecute(commandtoRun,"","","open","1");
}
function minimizefn(){
    var oShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
    var commandtoRun = "C:\Documents and Settings\cody\Desktop\C++ Programs\MINIMIZE001.def"; 
    oShell.ShellExecute(commandtoRun,"","","open","1");
}
function pocockfn(){
    var oShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
    var commandtoRun = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\cody\\Desktop\\C++ Programs\\POCOCK2001.def"; 
    oShell.ShellExecute(commandtoRun,"","","open","1");
}
//Another possible way of calling the .exe file from the web interface.
var objShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
</script>
```

Finally, I write the file in ASP (which doesn't work):

```
<%
    dim Study
    Study=Request.QueryString("Study")
    If Study<>"" Then
      Response.Write(Study)
    End If
    dim Site
    Site=Request.QueryString("Site")
    If Site<>"" Then
      Response.Write(Site)
    End If    
    dim Gender
    Gender=Request.QueryString("Gender")
    If Gender<>"" Then
      Response.Write(Gender)
    End If
    dim Age
    Age=Request.QueryString("Age")
    If Age<>"" Then
      Response.Write(Age)
    End If
    dim Result
    Result=Response.QueryString("Result")
    If Result<>"" Then
      Response.Write(Result)
    End If
%>
```

Does anybody have a cleaner way to create this application? It would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you really think a web page would allow you to run a program on the computer? Normally this is called a vulnerability... :)

Comment: A cleaner would to not mix ASP and PHP? So are you doing this as web and not windows app?

Comment: That's how viruses are spread. Why not do the exe processing server side?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this. The javascript runs on the client computer, which would mean that the program would be run on the client's computer and the files would need to be there as well. That defeats the purpose of having a web application.

Additionally, there are all sorts of very good security reasons to not allow in-browser javascript to run local executables - if that was supported, visiting a website could cause your computer to run, say, format.exe.

First, pick a single server-side web development framework. Don't try to combine PHP & ASP.NET. Second, figure out whether there's a way to handle this without a file on the filesystem and a command line utility. Can you do this logic in whatever development framework you picked? If you can't, you'll need to figure out how to write a file, how to shell out to call a .exe and how to return the results. None of these problems is particularly tricky on its own, and I'd tackle them one at a time, in that order.